# FreeBSD and GUIs

Tags: freebsd

From what I've heard, FreeBSD has no GUIs. Out of sheer curiosity, without even reading the handbook, I installed it onto a CD, then ran it. Only a terminal.

Naturally, I was confused. So I look around and see that it's not supposed to have GUIs. ([How to get to the GUI](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/how-to-get-to-the-gui.25359/))

Then I look at the handbook, and..

> FreeBSD is designed to provide a robust and full-featured environment for applications. It supports a wide variety of web browsers, office suites, email readers, graphics programs, programming environments, network servers, and much more.

**... What?**

I'm very confused. What am I missing here?

Comment: What on earth makes you think FreeBSD has no GUIs?

Comment: "**without even reading the handbook**" A word of advice when it comes to FreeBSD: ALWAYS RTFM. I've been flamed by them so many times because I didn't look in the right spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get graphical user environment, you should first install x server. Here you can find some information: [The X Window System](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/x11.html)

Then you can install GNOME, KDE, xfce, etc. See [Desktop Environments](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/x11-wm.html)

Comment: I figured that it'd be pre-configured for me in some way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For pre-configured, see PC-BSD.

Comment: Update regarding PC-BSD… Name changed, now spilt into two separate projects, TrueOS is the non-GUI OS derived from FreeBSD, and [Project Trident](http://www.project-trident.org/) is the GUI environment that runs on top of TrueOS. Other GUI projects may also run on TrueOS or other BSDs, such as GhostBSD.